# Permission denied for CPU temperature query

Tags: temperature

When I login as root user into my Raspberry Pi, then I query for temperature using this command:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/mode

-bash: /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/mode: Permission denied
```

I think I've broken down something. How can I repair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to execute that file which is not possible.

You want to view the content of the file which you can do like this:

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/mode
```

And if you want the temperature:

```
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

You need the divide the number you get by 1000 to get degrees C

Comment: Divide by what?

Comment: @Fred Odd, somehow that got cut.  I edited the answer.